# ¿Cómo depurar C++ en CLion?

Tags: compilar

Soy nueva en C++ y en CLion, e intenté buscar el problema que estoy teniendo pero no encontré soluciones así que recurro a la comunidad.

Había hecho un programa muy básico en el que el usuario ingresaba notas del 0 al 5 y se mostraba un informe de los aprobados, desaprobados, etc. Como era el primer programa estaba todo en un único archivo main.cpp

Decidí separarlo en un main.cpp, utils.cpp y utils.h pero algo debo estar haciendo mal, o algo tengo mal configurado en CLion porque no puedo depurar el programa.

El problema es que al ir a la ubicación del archivo y ejecutarlo, no me muestra los informes. Solo deja que cargue las notas y se cierra.

Me gustaría saber qué puedo hacer para poder debuggear en CLion y no tener que ver si compila y abrir el ejecutable.

Comment: Revertí tu edición pues no es correcto colocar la solución en la pregunta, para eso dispones justo abajo de la zona de respuestas, por favor considera agregarlo como respuesta